# Primefaces dialog doesn't close when action is completed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, growl

i have a dialog with two input fields and a commandButton, to add an object. If the user leaves a blank field a message growl is shown and the dialog stays open. But if the user completes all the fields and press the commandButton the object is added but the dialog doesn't close.

View.xhtml

```
<h:form id="allIncidenciasAux">
    <div id="divBotonCrear">
        <p:commandButton value="Añadir Incidencia" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"/>
    </div> <br/>

    <p:tabView>
        <p:tab title="All">
            <ui:repeat value="#{incidenciaBean.allIncidencias}" var="aux" >
                <p:panel id="basic" header="#{aux.titulo}" style="margin-bottom:20px" toggleable="true" collapsed="true" styleClass="#{ aux.solucionado eq 'false' ? 'incNS' : null}">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:panelGrid style="background-color: #B6C2DE; padding: 10px;">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha de publicacion: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{aux.fecha_publicacion}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Autor: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{aux.nombreCompleto}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <h:outputText value="Solucionado: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{aux.solucionado ? 'Si' : 'No'}"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <h:outputText value="Descripción: " style="font-weight: bold"/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{aux.descripcion}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid> <br/>
                </p:panel>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" life="8000"/>
</h:form> 

<h:form id="dialogAddIncidencia">
    <p:dialog id="newIncDialogo" header="Nueva Incidencia" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40" resizable="false">
        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{incidenciaBean.handleClose}" update=":dialogAddIncidencia"/> 
        <p:outputLabel value="Título"/> <br/>
        <p:inputTextarea id="tituloEdit" value="#{incidenciaBean.titulo}" rows="2" cols="50" counter="displayTA" maxlength="50" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes" autoResize="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Título necesario"/> <br/>
        <p:outputLabel id="displayTA"/> <br/> <br/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Descripción: "/> <br/>
        <p:inputTextarea id="descripcion" value="#{incidenciaBean.descripcion}" rows="10" cols="50" counter="displayDA" maxlength="200" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes" autoResize="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Descripción necesaria"/> <br/>
        <p:outputLabel id="displayDA"/> <br/> <br/>

        <p:commandButton value="Guardar Incidencia" action="#{incidenciaBean.insertIncidencia()}" oncomplete="if (#{incidenciaBean.camposNoVacios()}) dlg1.hide()" update=":allIncidenciasAux  :allIncidenciasAux:growl"/>
        <p:messages for="titulo"/> 
        <p:messages for="descripcion"/> 
    </p:dialog>    
</h:form>
```

Methods of incidenciaBean.java

```
public void insertIncidencia(){        
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    UsuarioBean usuarioHttp = (UsuarioBean) httpSession.getAttribute("usuarioSession");
    this.idComunidad = usuarioHttp.idComunidad;
    this.idUsuario = usuarioHttp.getIdUsuario();
    this.solucionado = false;
    this.fecha_solucion = null;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
    Date date = new Date();
    this.fecha_publicacion = dateFormat.format(date);

    if(ejb_incidencia.existIncidenciaTitulo(this.titulo, this.descripcion)){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error:",
                "Ya existe una incidencia con el mismo título y descripción."
              + "Por favor, compruebe que no se trata de la misma incidencia."));
    } else{
        ejb_incidencia.realizaRegistroIncidencia(this);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info:",
                "La incidencia se ha registrado correctamente"));
        initialStatusIncidencia();
    }

}

public boolean camposNoVacios(){
    return !(this.titulo == null || this.descripcion == null);
}

public void initialStatusIncidencia(){
    this.titulo = null;
    this.descripcion = null;
}

public void handleClose (CloseEvent event){
    initialStatusIncidencia();
}
```

Comment: Next time please start creating an [mcve]. Remove more and more code until it starts to work. I bet that if you change `oncomplete="if (#{incidenciaBean.camposNoVacios()}) dlg1.hide()"` to `oncomplete="dlg1.hide()"` it works.. The 'EL' in there is only evaluated when the html is rendered. Not when the oncomplete needs to be called. And next time also always post version info. See [ask], and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info to

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using `oncomplete`; however, I don't think your `if (#{incidenciaBean.camposNoVacios()})` statement ever evaluates true. The dialouge only hides if `camposNoVacios()` returns ture(if both`titulo` and `descripcion` aren't `null`). In `insertIncidencia()`'s else statement (which I assume is the success case) you set them to null with `initialStatusIncidencia()`.

So your program sets `titulo` and `descripcion`, checks that they aren't `null` in `insertIncidencia()`, and then sets them to `null` before checking to see if they aren't `null` with `camposNoVacios()`.